# How to assign an object to another object

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to model a program with 3 classes; Hotel, Room and Guest. I've already looked around on the site and altough some problems were similar, I didn't come across mine. The problem I have is that I'm not able to set a specific guest to a specific room. The code I have is as follows:

```
class Hotel{
  Room[] rooms;
  Hotel() {
    rooms = new Room[10];
    Guest Rob = new Guest("Rob");
    for (int j=0; j<rooms.length;j++){
      rooms[j] = new Room(null);
    }
  }

  Guest checkIn(Guest){
    for (int i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){
      if(rooms[i]!=null){
        rooms[i] = Guest;
        return;
      }
    }
 }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Hotel();
  }
}

class Room{
  Guest guest;

  Room (Guest n){
    this.guest = n;
  }
}

class Guest{
  String guestname;

  Guest(String n) {
    this.guestname = n; 
  }
}
```

Which is as far as I'm right now. I managed to create new guests, but now I want to be able to check for null in rooms (starting with the first room in the aray), and assign the guest to the first room in the array with null. 
I already made a method which I believe can do this; checkIn(Guest), but I'm unsure about what should be put inside to actually set the (guest) to the room[i].

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies for any formating errors, this is my first post here.

Kind regards,

Rob

Comment: `Guest checkIn(Guest)` is not a valid method signature, you need to provide a name for each parameter, e.g. `Guest checkIn(Guest myCoolGuest)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use getter and setter in your Room class .

Then, if `getGuest` returns null, the room is available, and you can call `setGuest` with the new guest.

```
public Guest getGuest(){

return guest;

}

public void setGuest(Guest guest){

this.guest = guest;

}
```

Your checkin method could be :

```
 void checkIn(Guest guest){

   for (int i=0; i<rooms.length; i++){

     Room room = rooms[i];

      if(room.getGuest() == null){
         room.setGuest(guest);
         return;
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! I'm trying this out right now, the code you entered results in an error "Guest cannot be converted to Room.Guest".
Apart from that, could you tell me -why- 'Room room = rooms[i]' has to be done during the checkIn method? I'm guessing it it so that the the room you refer to after that is the correct room[i], right?

Comment: The checkIn method should be where you placed yours, in Hotel (which owns the rooms). And it is the method where you have to iterate over your rooms : hence  the "for" loop and 'Room room = rooms[i]' . And yes you're right, the "room" variable obtained this way, refers to rooms[i]  in the next instructions.

Comment: Hi Berger, I'm sorry to bother you again. Not sure if it's common practice to make new questions or reply to old ones.
Anyway, I fixed the error I talked about by setting the code to room.setGuest(room.guest), instead of just guest. DRJava compiles the code just fine now. But when I run the code in CoffeeDregs(a sort of simulator, probably a known one?) it simply stops at the line "Room rooms = rooms[i]". 
Do you have any idea why that happens? I tried fixing it by declaring 'Room rooms' before starting the rest of the methods but that seems redundant and doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Guest checkIn(Guest guest){
    for(int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++){
      if(rooms[i] == null){
        rooms[i] = new Room(guest);
        return guest;
      }
    }
}
```

You seem like you are missing out on some Java (and OOP in general) naming conventions here.

`Guest Rob = new Guest("Rob");` 
Rob as the variable name should not be capitalized.

`this.guestname = n;`
Multiple words use camel-case convention, i.e. `guestName`. Also, you don't need to reference `this.guestName`, you can just say `guestName`. You would only need to use `this.guestName` if the parameter accepted by the method was also named `guestName`, i.e. `this.guestName = guestName`. Set the `guestName` field to private, also.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Doesn't this create a new room object with the guest in it, instead of linking them? Or is 'new Room(guest)' only used to link it?

Comment: This creates a new Room object, because you stated you wanted to find the first null value in the `rooms` array. If you meant "find the first Room object in the `rooms` array whose Guest member is null, " then the other answer has a good suggestion for that.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. Apologies for the confusion.